# Core Data model version is not available in file inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

i'am trying to use lightweight migration for Core Data Model file , after adding new Model file ,as you can see in image i can't see the " model version " section inside new model file's File Inspector for changing current version :

[image]

also my Xcode version is 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Model.xcdatamodeld folder (versioned core data model) in the project navigator.  If the file inspector still doesn't show the model version pop-up button, try again after re-launching Xcode.

Comment: i did this , but still can't see version sections !